# How to position this button to the right in this Navbar

Tags: css, reactjs, position, alignment, react-bootstrap

I'm new to this and learning React.
I try to set the hamburger toggle button in this [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/apple-basket-positioning-toggle-problem-deh4v?file=/src/components/elements/navbar.scss) to always be to the right but I have problems. The toogle must always be to the right with like `margin-right: 50px`

I use the [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/) `NavBar`.
As the image show the toggle button must be on the right but it's stuck.

[image]

When I set `margin-left: 100px;` the buttons in the above image is pushed on top of toggle

```
 .form-inline {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 100px;
  }
```

I also want margin-left but if I remove that it look ok:

[image]

I also use the `<Form inline>` so I have the items in a line and there are 2 columns only.
I try to make one column only and it did not work..

I have tried an abundant of combinations to make the toggle button stick to right side but no luck please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are some approaches to solve your current problem or even make your code structure much better. As @pat said earlier it's better to control your item positioning with grid tools, like flexbox and its relevant properties.

But if you just intend to move your toggle to the right side and you just defined two `Col` element *(Columns)*, you can simply move it around its container with `text-align` property *(In your particular case: `text-align: right;`)*. So if you want to do it with react-bootstrap built-in classes you can use `text-right` on the toggle container like this:

```html
<Navbar expand="false" bg="dark" variant="dark" fixed="top" collapseOnSelect className={`navbar`}>
  /* navbar brand */
  <Col>
      /* first col items */
  </Col>
  <Col className="text-right">
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
  </Col>
</Navbar>
```

Also, there is no need to add `margin-left` property to the `form-inline` class, because it will only move the left column to the right.

### Update

As I said earlier for managing your blocks it's better to use grid tools. So I just create a sandbox for that that you can see here:

[image: CodeSandbox]

I the above sandbox I just removed the `Col` items and add `d-flex` *(This is the equivalent of `display: flex;`, you can read more about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))* to the parent, which is the navbar itself. Then just add the `justify-content-between` which make sure there is always space between items in the same row whenever there is extra space available and finally to align them vertically I just used `align-items-center`. To make sure the form elements are always in the same line just added the `flex-nowrap` to the form element itself. Well, the elements in the smaller viewport will stack on top of each other, which the normal behaviour of flexbox but you can modify it however you want.

Comment: Thanks! If I remove the `margin-left: 100px;` from `form-inline` css then search and button jump back close to image and I dont want that I want evenly spaced itemed

Comment: @Kid Well, in your code box you did not have an image so I thought there is none. Let me provide a better solution for your particular case than to make everything aligned perfectly. Because the margin thing will not work very well in different viewports.

Comment: Yea right image was removed to make the code-sample easier

Comment: @Kid I just update the answer to give a better approach for your case.

Comment: You are a magician thanks this is perfect! I must read up on flexbox  to

Comment: [looks](https://codesandbox.io/s/apple-basket-working-navbar-ubw67?file=/src/components/elements/NavBar.jsx) much better now with your help also I inserted  logi inside the `flex-nowrap` thanks! :) Just need to fix the Media Query css

Answer (score 1):

```
<Navbar expand="false" bg="dark" variant="dark" fixed="top" collapseOnSelect className={`navbar`}>
  /* navbar brand */
  <Col>
      /* first col items */
  </Col>
  <Col className="toggle-nav">
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
  </Col>
</Navbar>


.toggle-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wouldn’t it be better if you’ve just wrapped those elements in a `class="wrapper"`, inserted the divs inside it and assigned the `justify-content` of this wrapper to `space-around` in the css ? I think it would be easier to do and also more responsive friendly.

Comment: Do you mean I could abandon the react-bootstrap `NavBar` and go Html?